# Memory leak in fetching data from sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have written a fetchAllFromDatabase for fetching the data from my db.
The Code is:

```
if ([tableName isEqualToString:kFavouriteStoresList]) {
                    NSMutableDictionary *dictFavStoreDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_ZipCode];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,1)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_StoreNumber]; // Leaking Memory
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,2)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_Address]; // memory leak
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,3)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_StoreName];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,4)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_City];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,5)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_State];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,6)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_Phone]; // Memory leak
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,7)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_Latitude];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,8)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_Longitude];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,9)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_sHrsMonToThu];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,10)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_sHrsFri];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,11)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_sHrsSat];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,12)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_sHrsSun];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,13)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_pHrsMonToThu];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,14)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_pHrsFri];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,15)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_pHrsSat];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,16)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_pHrsSun];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,17)] forKey:kFavouriteStoresList_StoreServicesList];

                    [tempFetchArray addObject:dictFavStoreDetails];
                    [dictFavStoreDetails release];
                    dictFavStoreDetails = nil;
                }
```

Here, I am getting a memory leak on 3 lines (see memory leak comment at the ned of this 3 lines). Can anyone tell me why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Static Analyzer ? If the case look carefully for the messages, sometimes the leaks are not placed at the right lines.